# Google Big Query: Determine invalid views (e.g. dryRun & list)

Tags: google-bigquery

We have several views in numerous projects & datasets in Google Big Query. Is there a way to list all invalid views? E.g. to "re-validate" all views and then to get a list?

While it might not cover all problems I think I could execute a view using the dryRun parameter to determine its state (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dry-run-queries). But in this case I would like to determine all existing views (over all projects, or - as this may be a bad idea - at least within one project) and then to trigger the view with the dryRun parameter and to store the results somewhere/somehow.

Hints how to do that are appreciated.

Regards,
HerrB92

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any built-in tools to do this, but it should be doable with some scripting.

`bq ls` command will return list of datasets, then for each dataset you can continue running `bq ls <dataset>` (or use `SELECT * FROM dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW'`), then run each view with `--dry_run` flag.